# How to stream data to a Bokeh server using Holoviews

Tags: python-3.x, server, streaming, bokeh, holoviews

I want to stream data generated by python to a webpage.
I came up with the following example, put together using examples from
https://holoviews.org/user_guide/Streaming_Data.html
and
http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Deploying_Bokeh_Apps.html
However I get a document lock error:
"'_pending_writes should be non-None when we have a document lock, and we should have the lock when the document changes'"

This is my example:

```py
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
import holoviews.plotting.bokeh
import streamz
import streamz.dataframe
renderer = hv.renderer('bokeh')
from holoviews import opts
from holoviews.streams import Pipe, Buffer
hv.extension('bokeh')


source_df = streamz.dataframe.Random(freq='5ms', interval='100ms')
sdf = (source_df-0.5).cumsum()
raw_dmap = hv.DynamicMap(hv.Curve, streams=[Buffer(sdf.x)])
smooth_dmap = hv.DynamicMap(hv.Curve, streams=[Buffer(sdf.x.rolling('50ms').mean())])

fig = (raw_dmap.relabel('raw') * smooth_dmap.relabel('smooth')).opts(
    opts.Curve(width=500, show_grid=True))

server = renderer.app(fig, show=True, new_window=True)
```

A page opens, figure shows up but is not updating. In my notebook I get the following error:

```py
tornado.application - ERROR - Exception in callback functools.partial(<function wrap.<locals>.null_wrapper at 0x00000234E3CB9400>, <Future finished exception=RuntimeError('_pending_writes should be non-None when we have a document lock, and we should have the lock when the document changes')>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 758, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 779, in _discard_future_result
    future.result()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1147, in run
    yielded = self.gen.send(value)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamz\dataframe\core.py", line 802, in _cb
    yield source._emit((last, now, freq))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamz\core.py", line 298, in _emit
    r = downstream.update(x, who=self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamz\core.py", line 563, in update
    return self._emit(result)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamz\core.py", line 298, in _emit
    r = downstream.update(x, who=self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamz\core.py", line 563, in update
    return self._emit(result)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamz\core.py", line 298, in _emit
    r = downstream.update(x, who=self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamz\core.py", line 747, in update
    return self._emit(result)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamz\core.py", line 298, in _emit
    r = downstream.update(x, who=self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamz\core.py", line 563, in update
    return self._emit(result)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamz\core.py", line 298, in _emit
    r = downstream.update(x, who=self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamz\core.py", line 563, in update
    return self._emit(result)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamz\core.py", line 298, in _emit
    r = downstream.update(x, who=self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamz\core.py", line 516, in update
    result = self.func(x, *self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\streams.py", line 436, in send
    self.event(data=data)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\streams.py", line 375, in event
    self.trigger([self])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\streams.py", line 156, in trigger
    subscriber(**dict(union))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\plot.py", line 615, in refresh
    self._trigger_refresh(stream_key)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\plot.py", line 624, in _trigger_refresh
    self.update(key)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\plot.py", line 596, in update
    item = self.__getitem__(key)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\plot.py", line 261, in __getitem__
    self.update_frame(frame)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\bokeh\element.py", line 1944, in update_frame
    self._update_ranges(element, ranges)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\bokeh\element.py", line 657, in _update_ranges
    self._shared['x'], self.logx, streaming)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\bokeh\element.py", line 702, in _update_range
    axis_range.trigger(k, old, new)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\model.py", line 599, in trigger
    super(Model, self).trigger(attr, old, new, hint=hint, setter=setter)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\util\callback_manager.py", line 143, in trigger
    self._document._notify_change(self, attr, old, new, hint, setter, invoke)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\document\document.py", line 1004, in _notify_change
    self._trigger_on_change(event)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\document\document.py", line 1099, in _trigger_on_change
    self._with_self_as_curdoc(invoke_callbacks)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\document\document.py", line 1112, in _with_self_as_curdoc
    return f()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\document\document.py", line 1098, in invoke_callbacks
    cb(event)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\document\document.py", line 668, in <lambda>
    self._callbacks[receiver] = lambda event: event.dispatch(receiver)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\document\events.py", line 244, in dispatch
    super(ModelChangedEvent, self).dispatch(receiver)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\document\events.py", line 126, in dispatch
    receiver._document_patched(self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\server\session.py", line 214, in _document_patched
    raise RuntimeError("_pending_writes should be non-None when we have a document lock, and we should have the lock when the document changes")
RuntimeError: _pending_writes should be non-None when we have a document lock, and we should have the lock when the document changes
```

Any clues what I'm doing wrong?
Kind regards

Comment: Bokeh expects updates to its objects to happen inside "locked" callbacks, e.g. inside its usual `on_change` or periodic or "next tick" callbacks. This error message happens when something has tried to circumvent that requirement, say by directly updating Bokeh objects from another thread outside of any Bokeh callback. It almost certainly indicates a usage error either in streamz or Holoviews.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the last line to `renderer.server_doc(fig)`, saved everything as a notebook named test.ipynb. In the command prompt, I ran `>bokeh serve --show .\test.ipynb`. The server is up and the streaming of data is shown in the browser as expected.

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
import holoviews.plotting.bokeh
import streamz
import streamz.dataframe
renderer = hv.renderer('bokeh')
from holoviews import opts
from holoviews.streams import Pipe, Buffer
hv.extension('bokeh')


source_df = streamz.dataframe.Random(freq='5ms', interval='100ms')
sdf = (source_df-0.5).cumsum()
raw_dmap = hv.DynamicMap(hv.Curve, streams=[Buffer(sdf.x)])
smooth_dmap = hv.DynamicMap(hv.Curve, streams=[Buffer(sdf.x.rolling('50ms').mean())])

fig = (raw_dmap.relabel('raw') * smooth_dmap.relabel('smooth')).opts(
    opts.Curve(width=500, show_grid=True))

renderer.server_doc(fig)
```